# Object has no method 'reduce' error when using arguments in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why do I get an error when using `arguments` like this?

```
function sum(){
    return arguments.reduce(function(a,b){
        console.log(a+b)
        return a+b;
    },0);
}

sum(1,2,3,4);
```

error:

```
/Users/bob/Documents/Code/Node/hello.js:2
return arguments.reduce(function(a,b){
                 ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'reduce'
    at sum (/Users/bob/Documents/Code/Node/hello.js:2:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bob/Documents/Code/Node/hello.js:8:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:903:3
```

This is from Mr. Crockford's [JS lectures](http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&feature=endscreen&v=ya4UHuXNygM).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`arguments` is not a real array, it's an "array-like" object and `reduce` is not a method of array-like objects. You can use `reduce` by passing `arguments` as context, like this:

```
[].reduce.call(arguments, function(a, b) {

});
```

**Edit:** more info on array-like objects here at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Working_with_Array-like_objects).

Comment: What is the difference between an array and an "array-like" object?

Comment: @AndersonGreen One inherits its prototype from `Array`, including goodies like `reduce`. The others don't, but still have numerical indices, which makes them resemble arrays.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Check my edit, there's some useful info at the MDN, scroll until you find the "array-like" heading.

Comment: This works:`function sum(){
 return [].reduce.call(arguments,function(a,b){
  console.log(a+b)
  return a+b;
 },0);
}

sum(1,2,3,4);` @elclanrs - thanks!

Comment: Don't know why Mr. Crockford did not put up a working example in his lecture?

Answer (score 1):

Crockford  explicitly states that using Array methods such as reduce() on arguments was introduced in ECMAscript 5.  Before ECMAscript5, not even Array had reduce() in all Javascript implementations. For things like map() and reduce(), I recommend using a library like Underscore which hides the implementation differences.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because `arguments` is an object not a list. Consider the following:

```
> function a(){ return arguments; }
> b = a(1, 2, 3);
> b
{ '0': 1,
  '1': 2,
  '2': 3 }
```

---

The MDN JavaScript documentation for [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) has more information, including:

> An Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.